# Leetcode #33 TIme Limit Exceeded

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array/

The question requires that the solution be O(log n) and I believe that my solution is O(log n) since my process of finding the smallest element is O(log n) and then using binary search to find the target value is also O(log n). However, my code is exceeding the time limit.

```
int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    if(nums.size() == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    int left = 0;
    int right = nums.size() - 1;
    while(left < right){
        int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if(nums[left] < nums[middle]){
            left = middle;
        }
        else{
            right = middle;
        }
    }
    if(target >= nums[0]){
        return binarySearch(nums, target, 0, left - 1);
    }
    else{
        return binarySearch(nums, target, left, nums.size() - 1);
    }
}

int binarySearch(vector<int>& nums, int target, int start, int end){
    if(nums.size() == 0 || (start == end && nums[start] != target)){
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
    if(nums[mid] == target){
        return mid;
    }
    if(nums[mid] > target){
        return binarySearch(nums, target, start, mid - 1);
    }
    else{
        return binarySearch(nums, target, mid, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it on your computer with test input?

Comment: it runs fine on my compiler and gives the correct output, but it is exceeding the time limit  on leetcode

Comment: Does leetcode let you know which input it causing the time limit exceeded issue?

Comment: Replace all of that code with `std::binary_search` or `std::upper_bound / std::lower_bound`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe binarySearch can run into an endless loop. When end = start + 1 you will get mid = start so if nums[start] < target you end up making a recursive call with the same parameters as before.

Comment: Same thing happens in the iterative binary search. Solution for the recursive binary search is to do `int mid = start + (end - start + 1) / 2` (or `int mid = start + (end - start) / 2 + ((end - start) & 1)` if you're paranoid about overflow) which will make the division round up.